# How to get value of input type text of html in to php and print?

Tags: php, html

I am stuck at a place where I a unable to get the value of input type of html to php. I am using Aptana to develop a website.

I didn't find any working answer in stackoverflow also.

I am just viewing the HTML file in my browser, is that a problem?

My code is as below:

FirstWebPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<h1 style="font-size:44pt" align="center">myPersonals.com</h1>

<h2 align="center">Welcome to your personal data center </h2>
<form action="welcome.php" method="get">
<div align="center">
<h3>Login</h3>
<input style="height:20px; width:200px; font-size:14pt" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" style="#b8b9c8">
<br>
<br>
<input style="height:20px; width:200px; font-size:14pt" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
<br>
<br>
<select name="sex" style="height:30px; width:200px; font-size:14pt">
<option value="m">Male</option>
<option value="f">Female</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input style="height:30px; width:200px; font-size:14pt" type="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
</div>
</form>
<a href="bigDB.jpg">
<img src="smallDB.jpg">'
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my welcome.php

```
 <html>
 <body>
 Welcome php Surendra Reddy your email id is <?php echo $_GET['email']; ?><br>
 and you are password is <?php echo $_GET['password']; ?><br>
 and your gender id <?php echo $_GET["sex"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is not printing the values.

Comment: do `<?php var_dump($_GET) ?>` to see if anything's coming across at all.

Comment: And are you running this on a web server, or just viewing the HTML file in your browser?

Comment: Don't forget to close your `<input>`

Comment: `style="#b8b9c8"` should be removed btw =o)

Comment: there are more than 2 genders

Comment: If you right submit the form and then view the HTML source of the page `welcome.php` do you still see your PHP code in the source? If so the PHP is not being executed.

Comment: I am just viewing it on browser

Comment: you need a web-server and php installed if you expect the php to work

Comment: @Marc B <?php var_dump($_GET) ?> it is also not working

Comment: @Suru Dagon is correct in above comment, you need to run it on a web server otherwise it's just treated as a HTML/text file not a PHP file and no code will execute.

Comment: when i am trying to run it as PHP Script it is showing "The current debugger dose not have any dined PHP executables. Please define a PHP executable location before continuing".

Comment: solution seems obvious **"define a PHP executable location"**

Comment: MY PROBLEM IS SOLVED WITH THE SUGGESTION OF Dagon AND CRYPTIC thanx

Answer (score -3):

/// will works if you use post instead get

I tried your code with post and get methods and runs good, you need try the code in xampp or something diferent that aptana, the code works, may could some about aptana server configurations

Comment: get should work fine, what's you bases for this answer?

Comment: That does not matter, POST or GET the value will still be sent. Just need to access the correct PHP superglobal.

Comment: i'd test the code with post and get, and in my computer work good, may check the server configuration is needed

Comment: fix it, by deleting your post :-)